# Unable to connect with kubectl to a GKE cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I am currently trying to connect with kubeclt to a GKE cluster.

I followed the steps in the documentation and executed successfully the following:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster_name> --zone <zone>
```

Some days ago it work perfectly fine. I was able to setup a connection with kubectl.
The configuration was not changed in any way. And also still try to accessing the cluster through the same network. The cluster itself is running stable. Whatever I try I run into a timeout.

I have already had a look into the kubectl configuration:

```
kubectl config view
```

It seems to be that the access token is expired.

```
...
expiry: "2022-08-01T12:12:35Z"
expiry-key: '{.credential.token_expiry}'
token-key: '{.credential.access_token}'
...
```

Is there any change to update the token? I am not able to update the token with the get-credential command. Already delete the configuration completely and run the command afterwards. But the token is still the same.

I am very thankful for any hints or ideas on this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rerunning your credentials command again to refresh your local kubeconfig?

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster_name> --zone <zone>
```

Alternatively, try the `beta` variant:

```
gcloud beta container clusters get-credentials <cluster_name> --zone <zone>
```

(You may need to install the beta package using `gcloud components install beta`)